# Proxmox, не синхронизируется нода

Tags: linux, proxmox

Есть 3 сервера.

Смысл в том, что два *phoenix* и *sparrow* нормально работают, а вот *blackcap* ни в какую не синкает. В чём может быть проблема?

```
root@blackcap:~# pvecm nodes
Node  Sts   Inc   Joined               Name
1   M  2878936   2015-06-16 18:14:43  blackcap
4   X      0                        phoenix
5   X      0                        sparrow

root@blackcap:~# tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] Members Left:
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] Members Joined:
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] CLM CONFIGURATION 

CHANGE
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] New Configuration:
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] #011r(0) ip(192.168.30.58)
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] Members Left:
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CLM   ] Members Joined:
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [TOTEM ] A processor joined or left the membership and a new membership was formed.
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [CPG   ] chosen downlist: sender r(0) ip(192.168.30.58) ; members(old:1 left:0)
Jun 16 18:16:03 blackcap corosync[212860]:   [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
```

статус phoenix

```
root@phoenix:~# pvecm nodes
Node  Sts   Inc   Joined               Name
   1   X      0                        blackcap
   4   M  2621688   2015-06-16 17:21:11  phoenix
   5   X  2621700                        sparrow
```

cluster.conf

```
root@phoenix:~# cat /etc/pve/cluster.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cluster name="birds1" config_version="9">

  <cman keyfile="/var/lib/pve-cluster/corosync.authkey">
  </cman>

  <clusternodes>


  <clusternode name="phoenix" votes="1" nodeid="4"/>
  <clusternode name="sparrow" votes="1" nodeid="5"/>
<clusternode name="blackcap" votes="1" nodeid="1"/></clusternodes>

</cluster>
```

Comment: [перезапускать сервисы на ноде](http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/16333-How-to-resync-cluster-after-network-outage) не пробовали?

Comment: Вообще это было первое что я сделал. К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: ещё, вроде бы, время на нодах должно быть синхронизировано. надеюсь, тоже проверили?

Comment: Кластер работал долгое кол-во времени. Все простые проблемы которые могли возникнуть, я уже проверил.

Comment: тогда рекомедую обратиться в более «рыбное» на использующих *proxmox* место: на их форум, или, если с английским плохо, например, в рассылку *debian-russian* (помню, в ней встречались обсуждения *proxmox*-а).

Comment: Конечно будет смешно, но их форум - мёртвый. Я на ру ресурсах больше отзывов получил чем на офф форуме и у них в саппорте.

Comment: У них супер бизнесс ответ - If for whatever reason you would like to make that server to join again the same cluster, you have to reinstall pve on it from scratch

Comment: ну что, логичный ответ. а если приобрести техподдержку, то, вероятно, ещё и пошагово расскажут, как сделать *reinstall from scratch*. попробуйте вторую часть моего совета (про *debian-russian*).

Answer (score 1):

Похоже не проходят **multicast** между **phoenix**,**sparrow** и **blackcap**
Проверить можно запустив одновременно на всех трех нодах **omping**

Поставить **cluster-ssh** на системе, с которой можно подключиться к всем трем нодам по ssh. Выполнить

```
cssh 192.168.30.58,{phoenix ip},{sparrow ip}
```

откроется три дефолтовых терминала (в большинстве случаев это xterm), и GUI-панелька для ввода команд одновременно на все открытые терминалы. 
Запускаем

```
omping 192.168.30.58 {phoenix ip} {sparrow ip}
```

и через какое-то время ctrl+c и смотрим статистику проходят ли multicast/unicast на 192.168.30.58